# Find Facebook status updates that have a Location

Tags: facebook

It seems that occasionally my Facebook settings get tweaked and I have a bunch of Facebook status updates that include a location.

By and large, I **do not** want my status updates to have a location on them.

Is there a way to easily find all of the status updates I have posted where there is a location, and only those?

What I *don't* want to do is remove location from *all* of my status posts. There are a few that I purposely added location to. It's the ones where I didn't want a location added that I want to fix. I just need a way to find them easily.

Comment: I don't even see a way to remove the location from status updates.

Comment: Huh. I think there used to be. If I can't edit some of these I guess this question is moot.

Comment: Oh, there is is. In the drop down don't choose "Edit post"; choose "Change location" then blank it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, it's looking like the only practical solution is a third-party app.

I found [My Places](http://xtremelysocial.com/facebook/myplaces/) which seems to do what I want: find all of my status updates that have a location.

I would prefer not to give access/data to a third-party, but so far this is all I've found that is viable. Facebook by itself doesn't seem to offer an easy way to do what I want.

Comment: That can find all your status updates with a location, but does it let you change the location for those status updates?  According to this screenshot, there's no down arrow on the top-right corner of the status update: http://xtremelysocial.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/mp_mine.jpg

Comment: All I want to do is find them. I can manage changing the ones I need.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to find all of your status updates with a location.  Facebook's graph search currently does not support searching through your posts/status updates.  If you try typing in either "my posts at" or "my status updates at" in the top search box, Facebook will say "This search isn't available yet."  (The graph search does support location searches for other things such as photos - if you type in "my photos at" then it will suggest searches for your photos taken at various locations.)

Right now I think the only way for you to find all of your status updates with a location is to go to your Timeline, load all of your status updates, and then use the browser's Find function.

So first, go to your Facebook profile, and it will load the Timeline portion of your profile by default.  Then keep scrolling down until you get to the very bottom, which will be your earliest status update.  This may take a while if you have a lot of status updates.  When you finally get to the bottom, Facebook will have loaded a lot of your status updates, but not necessarily all of them.  Sometimes it only loads your "highlights" for certain months or years.  So use your browser's Find function (should be CTRL-F in Windows or Command-F on a Mac) and search for "HIGHLIGHTS".  Every time you find "HIGHLIGHTS" on the page, click the little down arrow next to it and "All Stories" will appear.  Click on "All Stories" to force Facebook to load all of your status updates for that period:

[image]

After you have clicked on "All Stories" for each instance of "HIGHLIGHTS" that appeared on the page, you will have loaded all of your status updates.  Then the matter becomes finding the status updates with a location.  Based on what I've seen, Facebook can use " at " or " in " to indicate the location of a status update.  You can see this from the following examples:
[image]

So you should use your browser's Find function to search for the strings " at " and " in " (with the spaces around the words) throughout the page to find your status updates with a location.  Obviously you'll find every occurrence of " at " and " in ", and some of those might not be status update locations, so you'll just have to skip those.  Every time you find a status update with a location you want to remove, click the down arrow on the upper right corner and click on "Change location" and then delete the location:

[image]

Unfortunately there is one more way that Facebook can indicate the location in a status update, and that is shown in this example:

[image]

As you can see, there's no " at " or " in " or any other words next to "New York, NY".  So the only way to find this type of location in a status update is to search for the name of the location itself, which means you will have to remember all of the locations that were ever saved in your status updates.  This will be a pain, but there's no easier way to find these locations.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was afraid of. I've been an active member since 2007. This is going to be pretty impractical for me. Lots of good information though. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

When you click in the Update Status box, you’ll see your closest city listed in the gray bar along the bottom. Mouse over that city and click the little ‘x’ to the right of it. Presto! No more location information tacked onto your status updates. If you want to restore it, just mouse over the now-blank area where the city used to appear, then click Add current city.Here is the snap of it

[image]

Well this was the case with auto location but I am from india I checked this when my mobile location is off it doesnt takes any location, where as on my pc it takes my nearest city but only when I choose add location option in your case as you said it takes by default So I am not facing that kind of problem because it asks me before posting my status to add or not. see this.

[image]
[image]

So it depends on me to add or not my location. cheers. All the best.

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood my question. I know _how_ to remove the location from my status update. What I'm trying to do is _find_ all of the status updates  that have a location.

Comment: Oh ok I am sorry..